# Upload file button for POST methods in Swagger for a ASP.NET Core 6 Web API?

Tags: swagger, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm working on an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API. I've got Swagger configured like so in my `Program.cs`:

```
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
    {
        Title = "Web API",
        Version = "v1"
    });

    var baseDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
    var commentsFileName = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Name + ".xml";
    var commentsFile = Path.Combine(baseDirectory, commentsFileName);
    c.IncludeXmlComments(commentsFile);
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
```

I've got a POST method in my controller like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("upload")]
    public IActionResult Post([FromForm] IFormFile file)
    {
    }
```

Why is that that in Swagger I have to fill out a form and I can't just upload a file with a click of a button? How can I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just do like this.
you don't need FromForm to be specified.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("upload")]
public IActionResult Post(IFormFile file)
{
}
```